# c pointers with functions

Tags: c, function, pointers

Write a program that will accept from the user the total number of seconds.  Pass this value along with the addresses of three variables – hours, minutes, seconds – to a function called `time()` that will calculate the number of hours, minutes and seconds.  Print this information from `main()`.

Help me plz how can i fix my code to make this program work the way it supposed to.

```
   /* Adham Hamade
 .
  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//function prototype
void time(int &,int &,int &, int);


    int main()
   {
   //Variables
    int num;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;


    //reference number variables 
    int *h = &hours;
    int *m = &minutes; 
    int *s = &seconds;


    printf("Please enter number of seconds");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    time(h, m, s, num);

    printf("\n\nTime is %d hrs %d mins %d secs", hours, minutes, seconds);


 getch();
 return 0 ;   
 }

 void time(int &h,int &m ,int &s, int num)
 {
      int sec;
      int min;
      int hr;
      int t;


      hr = num / 3600 ;
      t = num %3600;
      min = t/60;
      sec = t%60;

      hr = &h;
      min = &m;
      sec = &s;


 }
```

Comment: So what's not working can you tell?

Comment: Use a debugger, and end all `printf` format strings with `\n` or else call `fflush`

Comment: Creating pointers to variables just for the sake of maintaining aliases to them which are used whenever the address is required is a poor practice. You can eliminate the `h`, `m` and `s` variables, and just call `time` as `time(&hours, &minutes, &seconds, num)`. That function has to take pointers; there are no reference parameters in C.

Comment: There is already a `time` function in the C language, so when you define your own external function called `time`, you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @Kaz; How could you say that it invokes UB?

Comment: @haccks The ISO C standard says so. If you define an external name that is reserved (or already defined), there are no requirements about how the program should behave.

Comment: @Kaz: You are right in what the standard says, **but** `time()` is not reserved (as it doesn't start with two underscores or an underscore and an uppercase letter), *and* it is not defined as he isn't also including `<time.h>`. So it's not UB, just poor style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c with the wrong answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606261/c-with-the-wrong-answer)

Comment: @DevSolar time is reserved because there is a standard library function called `time`, not because `time` is in a reserved name space.  Including headers isn't what defines external names in C; headers only provide declarations.

Comment: @Kaz: Re-reading the standard, 7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers, seems to agree with you, not me. Not sure where I got this from; will check my trusty Plaugher when I get the chance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no call by reference in C, only pass by reference.
Change

```
void time(int &,int &,int &, int);
```

to

```
void time(int *, int *, int *, int);
```

In your function definition of `time`, change

```
 hr = &h;
 min = &m;
 sec = &s;
```

to

```
*h = hr;
*m = min;
*s = sec;
```

Comment: Ah how did i miss this!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this , just modified your program

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function prototype
 void time(int *h,int *m ,int *s, int num);


int main()
{
   //Variables
    int num;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    //reference number variables 
    int h ;
    int m ; 
    int s;


    printf("Please enter number of seconds");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    time(&hours, &minutes, &seconds, num);

    printf("\n\nTime is %d hrs %d mins %d secs", hours, minutes, seconds);


 getch();
 return 0 ;   
 }

 void time(int *h,int *m ,int *s, int num)
 {
      int sec;
      int min;
      int hr;
      int t;

      hr = num / 3600 ;
      t = num %3600;
      min = t/60;
      sec = t%60;

      *h= hr ;
      *m = min ;
      *s =sec ;
 }
```

The **call by reference** method of passing arguments to a function copies the address of an argument into the formal parameter. Inside the function, the address is used to access the actual argument used in the call. This means that changes made to the parameter affect the passed argument.

For passing functions by reference,
just pass the address of the variable which is to be modified ie; address of hours, minutes, seconds in the function call.  The address is obtained by prepending ampersand operator '&' . So giving '&hours' gives the address of the variable hours which is used in the function call gets assigned to a pointer in the function definition.

```
void time(int *h,int *m ,int *s, int num);
```

so a function call like

```
time(&hours, &minutes, &seconds, num);
```

defines that 
pointer *h points to the address of the variable hours,

pointer *m points to the address of the variable minutes,

pointer *s points to the address of the variable seconds,

and the value of number of seconds is assigned to num

**So any value assigned to the pointers reflects in the main function since they are referring to the memory location.**

Comment: I've added the explanation for the program, Thanks for your TIP