# c with the wrong answer

Tags: c, pointers

Write a program to dispense change. The user enters the amount paid and the amount due. The program determines how many dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies should be given as change. Ask the user for the two inputs (amount due and amount paid) in main() and then send these along with pointers to 5 parameters (dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies) to a function called change(), which will then calculate the number of each to give out. Print the results from main().

so my program is compiling good but am getting wrong answer. what am i doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//function prototype
void change( int *d, int *q, int *di, int *n, int *p, int paid, int due );


int main()
{
    //variables
    int paid;
    int due;
    int dollars;
    int quarters;
    int dimes;
    int nickels;
    int pennies;

    //reference variables
    int *d;
    int *q;
    int *di;
    int *n;
    int *p;

    printf( "Enter amount due: \n" );
    scanf( "%d", &due );

    printf( "Enter amount paid: \n" );
    scanf( "%d", &paid );

    change( &dollars, &quarters, &dimes, &nickels, &pennies, paid, due );

    printf( "Dollars = %d\nquarters = %d\ndimes =%d\nnickels = %d\npennies = %d", dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies );

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void change(int *d,int *q,int *di, int *n, int *p, int paid, int due )
{
    int dollarChange;
    int quarterChange;
    int dimeChange;
    int nickelChange;
    int pennyChange;
    int modu;
    int modu2;
    int modu3;
    int total;
    int penniestotal;

    total = due - paid;

    penniestotal = total * 100;

    dollarChange = penniestotal / 100;
    modu = penniestotal % 100;
    quarterChange = modu / 25;
    modu2 = modu % 25;
    dimeChange = modu2 / 10;
    modu3 = modu2 % 10;
    nickelChange = modu3 / 5;
    pennyChange = modu3 % 5;
}
```

Comment: This was being asked last week.  Isn't your assignment overdue?

Comment: How are you putting those values back into the places the pointers point to?

Comment: no i never had this last week lol

Comment: Couple of general thoughts for you - format your code and give your variables meaningful names (`d`, `q`, `di`, `n`, and `p` do not count). Programming is usually not a race to see who has the shortest code, and the extra readability will make it easier to debug and maintain your code.

Comment: You don't set ``d`` in the change function so the dollars will always be zero.  What you are doing wrong is not writing unit tests

Comment: can you show me what u mean

Comment: i changed my variable names so its more readable

Comment: Standard debugging procedure: 1) Cut away source not directly contributing to the problem. 2) Check that problem persists. 3) Repeat first two steps until you can no longer cut away source without making the problem disappear. Now you have either understood where your problem comes from, or you have arrived at example code *that doesn't take ten minutes to make sense of*. I am pretty sure your problem stems from *one* misuse of pointers, not the interaction of a dozen of them.

Comment: this program has two fundamental problems.  First the "change" and "due" parameters are apparently fractional parts of dollars.  eg $1.25  But the scanf input and the function both use integers.  Second, consider how the results are passed back from the function ``change``.  The variables set like dimeChange, quarterChange, nickelChange, pennyChange are not visible in the calling function and are not passed back.

Comment: Please read this before you post more questions to SO. These are low-quality questions and are likely to be deleted. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

`change()` takes lots of pointers as arguments, but those pointers are never used in the function. There's also no return value.

Which means that nothing you do in `check()` actually matters.

You're reading `due` and `paid` from the input, then you call a function that doesn't matter, and then you print lots of uninitialized variables to output.

**Postscriptum:**

You've asked five questions so far, each of them following a similar pattern: Explaining what your program should do, a line of "it does not work", and a code dump.

*That is not how StackOverflow, or any other Q&A site, works.*

Your problem here, for example, is not "calculating change", it's "parameter passing". Like all other questions you posted, it could conceivably be expressed in ten lines of code, *maximum*. That you dumped your change calculation on us instead shows a lack of effort on your part, which is why you keep getting downvotes.

**Postscriptum 2:**

I visited your other questions. Four out of five questions are basically identical: You have not understood how pointers and parameter passing work. Since your questions are so nebulous, you get answers that are all over the place, which isn't very helpful. Then you went trial & error without really understanding what you're doing, and your programs actually got *worse* with each try...

So, for your consideration, a program that does some pointing-to and parameter passing, does it right, does it with only one parameter at a time, and is quite verbose about what it is doing. Study it, it really answers your last four questions in one go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function( int * parameter )
{
    int local = 987;

    printf( "Address of 'local' is:                     %p\n", &local );
    printf( "Value of 'local' is:                       %d\n\n", local );

    printf( "Address that 'parameter' points to is:     %p\n", parameter );
    printf( "Value at that address is:                  %d\n\n", *parameter );

    puts( "Switching 'parameter' to point to 'local'...\n" );

    int * copy_of_parameter = parameter;

    parameter = &local;

    printf( "Address that 'parameter' NOW points to is: %p\n", parameter );
    printf( "Value at that address is:                  %d\n\n", *parameter );

    puts( "Changing value of 'local' through 'parameter'...\n" );

    *parameter = 0;

    printf( "Address that 'parameter' points to is:     %p\n", parameter );
    printf( "Value at that address is:                  %d\n\n", *parameter );

    puts( "Making 'parameter' point at the old address again...\n" );

    parameter = copy_of_parameter;

    *parameter = 666;

    printf( "Address that 'parameter' NOW points to is: %p\n", parameter );
    printf( "Value at that address is:                  %d\n\n", *parameter );

    return;
}


int main()
{
    int in_main = 123;

    printf( "Address of 'in_main' is:                   %p\n", &in_main );
    printf( "Value at that address is:                  %d\n\n", in_main );

    puts( "Calling function()...\n" );

    function( &in_main );

    puts( "Returned from function()...\n" );

    printf( "Address of 'in_main' is:                   %p\n", &in_main );
    printf( "Value at that address is:                  %d\n\n", in_main );

    return 0;
}
```